# How to get Tax Percentage of a product in Magento cart?

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get a Tax Percentage of a product in a current cart using following code but it doesn't return anything, can anyone please tell me if i am using wrong function or method.

```
$t = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
echo $t->getTaxPercent();
```

This below code works and it returns the Grand Total

```
echo $t->getGrandTotal();
```

These below two lines works and returns tax % when I am trying to get tax % of historic orders:

```
$t = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
echo $t->getTaxPercent();
```